# Change/Remove Google Analytics account in web console

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

Looking to setup GA tracking for my app (both, Android & iOS), the documentation led me to:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Now after adding [GA account added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLoF8.jpg)

I need to change the GA account to another existing one.
I don't see any provision either here, or in the dev console.

Do help point me to the right place where this can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Work around for now:

- Remove yourself, from the GA acccount (Of course make sure someone can add you back)
- Reload the page, the account selection dropdown is now available

As an aside, within the  Google Dev Console,

GDC > My App > Credentials

an iOS and Android key is auto added, on account selection.